The "Encrypted String" and "String Hidden" type in the ArcGIS Pro tool parameter
I am developing a customized script geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Pro and need to securely handle user credentials. For the password input, I used the data types "Encrypted String" and "String Hidden" to mask the password. When I test my tool, it uses * to hide my password, which works as expected. However, I noticed that the tool passes only the masked characters ("*****") to my Python script instead of decrypting it. Do I need to decrypt the password within my script? If so, how can I achieve this?
